# C# DBF File default ordering

Tags: c#, oledb, foxpro, dbf

I need to write records to a DBF file in C# (which is working fine) but the requirement is that when the user opens the resulting dbf file, the records are sorted according the values in one of the columns. I have accomplished this with other formats by simply setting the column as the primary key. However, I am unable to create a primary key, as I get the the error ("not supported for non-dbc"). Is there any other way I can achieve the "sorting"?

Comment: We can't help without seeing the code.

Comment: There is no code to show. I can work with a DBF file just fine, but it appears that you can't create a primary key on a free table. I am posing a question if there is another way to achieve the ordering in the table.

Comment: Is it not possible to write the records out in the order you want them seen? i.e. physically ordering the file? Alternatively, can't you append the records to a DBF that already has the key defined?

Comment: I am writing them in order, but when I open it, it is ordering using some arbitrary column. The files that I am processing do not have keys.

Answer (score 0):

Data being stored in a DBF or any other database is NOT ever stored sequentially but utilize indexes and ORDER BY clauses when retrieving data.  So, I would just worry about your query when RETRIEVING the data to include as such...

select * from whateverTable order by Column1, Column8, Column20
(or whatever columns are of concern)

Then, it doesn't matter WHAT order they are actually entered....

Comment: I completely understand this, but I am not retrieving the data, the client is. It needs to have a default ordering.

Comment: In terms of the internal file structure data in a DBF is always stored in the order that records are added. If you retrieve them with no active index, or ordering imposed in an Select-SQL statement, they will come back in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

For free DBF files, you will need to write the records in the order you wish for them to appear.

Note: I know your comment above says you are doing this, but this is the answer. If you don't tell us and/or show us how you are writing out to the table, we can't help any further.

Answer (score 0):

Tables that aren't in a database ("free tables" in foxpro nomenclature) support [Candidate indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9w73shy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#foconvisualfoxproindextypesanchor2):

> Similar to a primary index, a
>   candidate index contains an index key
>   for each record in a table and
>   prohibits duplicate values in the
>   fields or index expression specified
>   for generating index keys.